# GraphQL query response is the response object with null inside ( Spring 3 + Kotlin + GraphQL + DGSCodeGen )

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, graphql-java, netflix-dgs

Has the title says, I created an object and that receives various inputs and
then on GraphiQL I query it and then it only returns the response object with a null inside.

Have this happened to anyone else ?

I thought it was because the models were not the same as the query objects, but it still returns null with the dgs code gen.